# Identify version of UCSD P-System disks?

Tags: ucsd-p-system

I have a DOS-hosted UCSD P-System running under DOSBox. The "boot" drive for it has to be IV, but the .VOL files that I have - from several sources - don't necessarily contain .CODE files for version IV. I'm fairly sure that at least one set of .VOL files I have are for version III, and others are just completely unknown. Is there some reasonably easy way that I can determine what version a given .CODE file is for?

Answer (score 3):

The segment dictionary of the code file has an entry that describes the version. See e.g. the [Pascal Internal Architecture Guide](http://pascal.hansotten.com/uploads/ucsd/softech/UCSD%20P-System%20&%20UCSD%20PASCAL_Internal_Architecture_Guide.pdf), p. 28.

I once wrote an UCSD Pascal program that disassembled code files, so writing a similar program to look at that particular field for each segment shouldn't be too difficult.