# How can I tell which compiler I have on my UCSD P-system IV disks?

Tags: ucsd-p-system

I have a MS-DOS-hosted UCSD P-system IV, where the disks have been converted to named VOL image files. One of these is called VOLITION, and contains a compiler on it. However, since the compiler is always called SYSTEM.COMPILER, it's not apparent whether this is a Pascal compiler or their Modula-2 compiler. Is there some way to determine which this is, given that I have *no* documentation associated with it?

Comment: Feed it some Modula-2 source code and see if it throws up?

Comment: Listing out the ASCII text contained in the image should give clues. The `strings` command can do it (for windows a version is available in the Windows Sysinternals collection of utilities and most Linux/Unix have the command available.)

Comment: @Brian Does `strings` even exist on MS DOS.

Comment: Seems pretty similar to your other question, <https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18364/15334>, if it’s not an outright duplicate.

Comment: No, that one was about identifying the version of the P-System. Here, I know that the "disk" is for P-System IV, (though not 'bootable' on the DOS-hosted P-System) but I don't know whether the `SYSTEM.COMPILER` is a Pascal compiler or a Modula-2 compiler.

Comment: @OmarL The question mentions VOL images files so I assumed those image files can have strings extracted pretty easy form a more modern system.

Comment: @Brian I recall the "strings" command existing on MS-DOS as a third-party utility.

Comment: I'm actually hosting the MS-DOS P-System on DOSBox running on a Win10 box, so I _can_ use Window utilities - with a little effort - to explore the UCSD 'disks'.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if you have a copy of the Volition Systems Modula-2 compiler ([documentation](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_volitionSy20.3jIBMPC_14753891/mode/2up)).  The docs and this [PC Mag review](https://books.google.com/books?id=e-gI2W-3JwkC&lpg=PA191&ots=V-GisIZuay&dq=volition%20compiler&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q=volition%20compiler&f=false) indicate the compiler was built on top of the UCSD Pascal system (but that does not necessarily mean the tool will *compile* Pascal, only Modula-2).

Comment: That's more-or-less the question - is the "disk" that I have the one from Volition's _Pascal_ compiler on the P-System, or the _Modula-2_ compiler on the P-System? As I indicated, I have no documentation with it (though I have plenty of documentation for the P-System itself, and IBM's P-System Pascal and FORTRAN compiler manuals).

Comment: I couldn't locate any reference to Volition's Pascal compiler, only their Modula-2 compiler and UCSD Pascal v.III runtime, until I found this buried in an archive of a Yahoo! Groups mailing list (http://archive.retro.co.za/archive/YahooGroups/UCSDPascal.html):

Comment: "Get the Volition.VOL system of mine that Randy McLaughlin uploaded in the file area.. ... you could just boot the volition disk without any changes. From memory there is a blindingly fast II.0 pascal compiler on one of the
volition disks as well as the ASE editor, and an M2 compiler."  Since it's called SYSTEM.COMPILER, I wonder if that's the P-code compiler ("system"), as UCSD Pascal's runtime was often referred to as an "operating system" back in the day.

Comment: `SYSTEM.COMPILER` is always the compiler invoked by the `C(ompile` or `R(un` commands - depending on how your P-system is set up, it might be Pascal, FORTRAN 77, Modula-2, or whatever (I've also heard of a BASIC for UCSD, but never seen it). As far as the YG archive, that implies that what I have as VOLITION.VOL may be the P-System II compiler, not the P-System IV version. :(